# Strict Aliasing how resolve?

Tags: c++

```
inline void addHeader(T value)
{
    if(sizeof(T) > m_outputBufferStart)
    {
        std::clog << "[Error - OutputMessage::addHeader] m_outputBufferStart(" << m_outputBufferStart << ") < " << sizeof(T) << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    m_outputBufferStart -= sizeof(T);
    *(T*)(m_buffer + m_outputBufferStart) = value; //here is error
    m_size += sizeof(T); //current size of buffer
}
```

my question is how can I solve strict aliasing? I don't want to "skip" this warning,

buffer is array of uint8_t

Comment: you could always use [placement-syntax] and the copy-constructor (and pass `value` by const-reference, btw). It better be a trivial type if you're going to do this, btw.

Comment: it takes too much time to alloc/realloc memory, anyway my solution works

Comment: What is the type of `m_outputBufferStart`? I guess it's `char*`?

Answer (score 1):

The warning can be silenced by casting the array value to an integer for doing the pointer arithmetic.

```
*(T*)((uintptr_t)m_buffer + m_outputBufferStart) = value;
```

A more C++y way would probably be to cast the type to a pointer and then copying it to the buffer.

```
std::copy_n(&m_buffer[m_outputBufferStart], sizeof(T), (uint8_t*)value);
```

Comment: I guess this hides the warning, but is it possible that the strict aliasing "bug" hasn't been resolved? And therefore that further changes are required?

Comment: @AaronMcDaid Looking back at this it seems like the code in the question doesn't have a strict aliasing violation. Can't really tell how OP generated the warning or how my answer would have helped.